# Fit and Predict Arima in R

Tags: r, predict, arima

I am trying to fit a Arima model in R with an independent variable (ARIMAX). 
The model fit data contains both positive and negative numbers. The issue is that after fitting the model, the predict function throws out numbers which are not even close to data that was used to fit the model.

```
# Sample Data
y <- c( -0.05628948,  0.01907727,  0.00000000, -0.01907727,  0.00000000, -0.01940678,
0.05724351, -0.01875946, -0.03848405,  0.05724351)
x <- c(0.000000000,-0.071700531 ,-0.023863364,  0.013701646,  0.000000000,  0.085009788,
  -0.028666940, -0.046181130, -0.027316528,  0.006895152)

#Fit the model
model <- arima(y, order=c(2,0,1),fixed = c(NA,NA,NA,NA,NA),xreg=x)

#Use the predict function with x again as the input
fore <- predict(model,newxreg = x)[1]

########################Output########################################
Model - 
Call:
arima(y, order = c(2, 0, 1), xreg = x, fixed = c(NA, NA, NA, NA, NA))

Coefficients:
         ar1      ar2      ma1  intercept       x
      -0.7935  -0.5747  -0.2986    -0.0010  0.0569
s.e.   0.4327   0.4399   0.6892     0.0026  0.1245

sigma^2 estimated as 0.0005055:  log likelihood = 22.91,  aic = -33.83

Predict - 

> fore
$`pred`
Time Series:
Start = 11 
End = 20 
Frequency = 1 
[1] -0.03206240 -0.03614031 -0.03341961 -0.03128313 -0.03206240 -0.02722754
[7] -0.03369281 -0.03468892 -0.03361601 -0.03167025
```

Not sure why all the values from predict are only negative (while the original y has both positive and negative) and so off from the original y values. Please advise. Thanks!

[image: x and y]

Answer (score 0):

There are a few things going on here. One is that you are using `predict` without the `n.ahead` argument. This is predicting the next value (at time 11 in this example) and then just using the x argument to change that prediction slightly over the next 9 values (`n.ahead = 1` is the default of predict.Arima). To get an actual prediction of the time series, either use `forecast` or `predict` with `n.ahead = 10`.

Another thing is that you shouldn't expect the numbers of the prediction for the next 10 time periods to be what the previous 10 observations were even with the same x values. The ar and ma coefficients will send the predictions in a direction. There is a lot here in regards to the short memory of the ma variables etc., but the main point is that predictions into the future will not be the same as the past even if the x-variable is the same (as in the case of this example).

I think that your main concerns are addressed in the first paragraph. Here are the predictions with `n.ahead = 10` or using the `forecast` function.

```
fore <- predict(model,newxreg = x, n.ahead = 10)[1]
fore

$pred
Time Series:
Start = 11 
End = 20 
Frequency = 1 
 [1] -0.032062405 -0.013745753  0.022305060 -0.014876850 -0.003612005
 [6]  0.014262754 -0.009471801 -0.004258822  0.001812099 -0.003776596

forecast(model, xreg = x)
   Point Forecast       Lo 80       Hi 80       Lo 95      Hi 95
11   -0.032062405 -0.06087474 -0.00325007 -0.07612707 0.01200226
12   -0.013745753 -0.05641143  0.02891993 -0.07899728 0.05150577
13    0.022305060 -0.02118176  0.06579188 -0.04420229 0.08881241
14   -0.014876850 -0.05983585  0.03008215 -0.08363571 0.05388201
15   -0.003612005 -0.05066734  0.04344333 -0.07557693 0.06835292
16    0.014262754 -0.03300372  0.06152923 -0.05802508 0.08655059
17   -0.009471801 -0.05694644  0.03800283 -0.08207799 0.06313439
18   -0.004258822 -0.05212230  0.04360466 -0.07745970 0.06894205
19    0.001812099 -0.04610561  0.04972981 -0.07147172 0.07509592
20   -0.003776596 -0.05172413  0.04417094 -0.07710602 0.06955283
```

Comment: Thanks for answering that, really appreciate it. When I use the forecast function as you mentioned, I get an error  saying Error in predict.Arima(object, n.ahead = h) : 
  'xreg' and 'newxreg' have different numbers of columns

Comment: Yes, you need to make sure that the number of values in `xreg` in the `forecast` function equals what you put in for `h`.

Comment: Sorry, I didn't read the error closely. It is saying that when you built the model you had a certain number of x variables (say 2) and when you are predicting with the forecast function you no longer have 2 variables. Make sure that the structure that is used to make the model is the same as the structure used to predict.

Answer (score 0):

Add lambda =0 in auto.arima / arima to get forecast in positive.